# How to search for file in directory with only part of filename?

Tags: node.js, csv, fs

Say a folder has a bunch of files named like this:

```
XjAsxREAAEbmh6yz$5a0cafce-a42a-4ea6-a626-404db4666b41.json
```

And I want to read that specific file by searching for everything before the $ sign, like so:

```
XjAsxREAAEbmh6yz
```

How would you do this in node.js?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith?

Comment: read all file names from directory, pick only the matching ones

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var orginalFile = "XjAsxREAAEbmh6yz$5a0cafce-a42a-4ea6-a626-404db4666b41.json";
var search =  orginalFile.substring(0, s.indexOf('$'));
fs.readdirSync("./directory")
.filter(file => file.startsWith(search) && file.endsWith(".json"))
.forEach(file => {
    const result = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./directory/${file}`));
    console.log(result);
});
```